# Updated value must stay between two values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a variable in my game that adds points and sometimes substract points.
In my database I have a score table but the value of the score must always be between 0 and 20. 

 So if my score is currently 2 and the variable $value is -3 I can avoid to go under 0 by doing this.

```
UPDATE  table
SET     field = GREATEST(0, field + $value)
WHERE   id = $id
```

Is there a way so that the value won't go under 0 and not above 20?

Comment: `set field = case when field + value < 0 then 0 when field+value > 20 then 20 else field+value end`

Comment: Are you sure you want to put your business logic into you database layer ? You could consider having that piece of code a layer above - would be much easier to change later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a case expression.

```
UPDATE  [table]
SET [field] = CASE
                  WHEN [field] + @value > 20
                       THEN 20
                  WHEN [field] + @value < 0
                       THEN 0
                  ELSE [field] + @value
              END
WHERE   [id] = @ID;
```

Comment: Glad to help!  Remember to [accept answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) that work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can nest GREATEST and LEAST like this to achieve what you want.

```
UPDATE  table
SET     field = GREATEST(0, LEAST(20, field + $value))
WHERE   id = $id
```